# Have checked words added to a sentence on submit using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this list

```
<form>
    <input name="Dog" type="checkbox" value="Dog">Dogs<br>
    <input name="Cat" type="checkbox" value="Cat">Cats<br>
    <input name="Bird" type="checkbox" value="Bird">Birds<br>
    <input name="Rabbit" type="checkbox" value="Rabbit">Rabbit<br>

    <input name="FavAnimals" type="button" value="Show my favorite animals">
</form>
```

What I want to happen is that when someone selects their favorite animals and hit the the button 'Show my favorite animals', a sentence will appear on the same page that shows your selections using.

Example 1:

Your favorite animals are dogs, cats, and birds!

Example 2:

Your favorite animals are dogs and cats!

Example 3:

Your favorite animal is a dog!

So there would have to be 3 different types of sentences. If 3 or more is selected, the commas and the word and would be needed, so 'animal, animal, and animal'. If 2 are selected it would be 'animal **and** animal'. If 1 is selected, then instead of your favorite animals **are**, it'd be your favorite animal **is**.

I want to use jQuery but am having trouble thinking on how to go about this. I'm fairly new so any help would be great.

Comment: so you basically want to dynamically display a sentence as the user selects animals, right?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Can you display your attempt(s) so we can see where the problem is?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so when you hit submit, a sentence will appear of the animals you have selected. And every time you hit submit again, it refreshes the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want.

I've added a `sentence` div - for putting the sentence in. It takes into account how many items have been selected, and chooses whether it should say `is` or `are` and then if it is `are` then on the last item, it will say `and`:

```js
var $sentence = $('#sentence');

$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {

  var total = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
  if (total == 1) {
    $('#sentence').text("Your favourite animal is a " + $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val());
  } else {
    $('#sentence').text("Your favourite animals are ");
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i) {
      if (i == total - 1) {
        $sentence.append('and ' + $(this).val());
      } else {
        $sentence.append($(this).val() + ', ');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="Dog" type="checkbox" value="dogs">Dogs
  <br>
  <input name="Cat" type="checkbox" value="cats">Cats
  <br>
  <input name="Bird" type="checkbox" value="birds">Birds
  <br>
  <input name="Rabbit" type="checkbox" value="rabbits">Rabbit
  <br>
  <input name="FavAnimals" type="button" value="Show my favorite animals">
</form>
<div id='sentence'></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shub01/y5prrfvb/4/)

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to make it so it refreshes and changes every time instead of adding a new sentence every time the submit button is pressed?

Comment: $('#sentence').text("Your favourite animals are ");

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, just clears text instead of appending (this is what OP asked for), when another selection is made... :) http://jsfiddle.net/y5prrfvb/3/

Answer (score 3):

Edit: comprehensive answer

```
$('[name=FavAnimals]').click(function () {
    var $inputs = $(':checkbox:checked'),
        message = 'Please select animals';
    if ($inputs.length) {
        var animals = $.map($inputs, function (input) {
            return $(input).val();
        });

        message = 'your favorite animal';
        if (animals.length > 1) {
            message += 's are '
            message += animals.slice(0, animals.length - 1).join(', ');
            message += ' and ' + animals.pop();
        } else {
            message += ' is ' + animals.shift();
        }

    }
    $('#message').text(message);

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrbkxb3k/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: @msbodetti that's why I said they could build upon it. feel free to provide a more comprehensive answer yourself

Comment: actually it's a bit cleaner since it doesn't add extra comma and also covers case where nothing is selected